# Svn pre-commit hook for checkstyle

Tags: svn, hook, checkstyle, pre-commit

Here is my current checkstyle shell script. It works fine if I commit on TRUNK but not on Branches. I don't really understand why it doesn't work. Can someone please help me?

```
#!/bin/sh

###################################################
#
# Verify Checkstyle
#
###################################################

REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"

SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook
JAVA=/opt/ibm/java2-i386-50/bin/java
CHECKSTYLE=/usr/local/checkstyle/checkstyle-all-5.1.jar
TMPDIR=/tmp/$TXN
REPORT=/tmp/$TXN/report
CHECKSTYLE_CONFIG=/usr/local/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml

CHANGED=`$SVNLOOK changed -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | grep -v "^D" | awk '{print $2}'`
mkdir -p $TMPDIR
for LINE in $CHANGED ; do
    FILE=`echo $LINE | egrep -v Test\\.java$ | egrep -v \\/src\\/test\\/ | egrep -v \\/js\\/ext`
    if [ -n "$FILE" ] ; then
        DIRNAME=`dirname $FILE`
        mkdir -p $TMPDIR/$DIRNAME
        $SVNLOOK cat $REPOS --transaction $TXN $FILE > $TMPDIR/$FILE
    fi
done
$JAVA -jar $CHECKSTYLE -c $CHECKSTYLE_CONFIG -r $TMPDIR > $TMPDIR/tmpfile.checkstyle
X=$?
if [ $X -ne 0 ] ; then
    cat $TMPDIR/tmpfile.checkstyle > /dev/stderr
    rm -Rf $TMPDIR
    exit 1
fi
rm -Rf $TMPDIR

exit 0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Word of advice: Don't make this a pre-commit script.

- Any pre-commit script will hold up the commit until it completes. If I check in a dozen files, how long does it take for this script to run? When I first got into computing, a second second response time was considered acceptable. Now, if you don't get a response in a few seconds, people will complain.
- What happens in those cases where the `checkstyle` catches something where it is not an issue, or the way the developer wrote it is actually clearer and easier to understand than what `checkstyle` insists it should be? When you use something like `checkstyle` or `findbugs`, you have to understand you'll get a few false positives.

A better method is to use a continuous build engine like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org). Jenkins can be setup to automatically kick off a build with each and every commit. Jenkins can:

- Automatically store the results of the build. Then, you can actually release the code directly from Jenkins for testing and for your clients. After all, you know the same jar/ear/war files you've tested are the same ones your customers will get.
- Automatically run various tests including:

  - Checkstyle
  - Findbugs
  - Corbertura
  - PMD
  - DRY
  - JUnit
  - Check for built warnings
  - And dozens of others
- Jenkins saves the entire build output, all saved artifacts, and all tests in a nice and easy to see webpage that is available to any user.
- Jenkins can integrate into a wide variety of issue tracking tools, so you can see what Jenkins build a particular issue was involved in.

You don't have to use Jenkins. Hudson is still there. So is CruiseControl, and you can use TeamCity, Bamboo, and dozens of other continuous build systems out there. I like Jenkins because development is very active, and it's dead simple to setup. It took me about 30 minutes to download it and run my first job the very first time I heard of it.

I know you asked about your pre-commit hook, and I don't want to sound like a salesman (Jenkins is free and open source, and I have no connection to the project), but making something as complex as a `checkstyle` check a pre-commit hook is asking for trouble. Using a continuous build server is simply a better way of handling this issue.

Comment: I disagree. I also use and like Jenkins but checking coding conventions should be done _before_ a commit completes. Otherwise it's too late and your subversion diffs are already messed up by meaningless formatting changes. That's why, IMO, a commit should only complete if the code meets your style requirements.

Comment: There are two issues: One is time. If it takes 5 to 10 seconds for a commit to complete, your developers will do fewer commits which is not what you want. The second is false positive in violations. What if the code style checker returns a false violation? You can't commit the code, or spend 20 to 30 minutes trying to munge your code until the tool is happy? Give the devs the means of doing the check before commit, and fail builds with code style with too many violations. Reverse bad commits. The devs will learn to do their Code Style checks before commits, it'll become part of your culture.

Comment: First, it's a best practice to keep commits as small as possible. Checking <=5 files for style compliance won't take long. Second, I heavily doubt that waiting for 10 seconds will deter people from committing often. It certainly won't deter me. And finally, false positives are not an issue. I don't know about checkstyle, but tools like [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com) allow you to suppress errors and warnings on a case per case basis.

Comment: Oh, I forgot the most important issue with doing the checks during building: You cannot check only modified files after the commit. That's a big problem when introducing a style checker in existing projects because it's infeasible for a dev to fix all files (even all files in a project/package). Sure, you could also treat the violations as warnings instead of errors. But the devs will ignore those, just like the other build warnings. (Consider yourself lucky if you work with different people.) Instead, I'd prefer having a dev fix only the files (s)he modified. IMO that's simple and makes sense

Comment: I think one should prevent nasty commits (even though false positives are a risk). Regarding 'fewer commits' in my opinion is best, Ideally I want one commit per #issue, not many, that involve all necessary changes to overcome the issue, plus tiny  commits related to the changes' bugfix. +10 for the jenkins salesman speech haha

Answer (score 0):

A hint.

Try to compare the directory structure, whitch you create temporary (remove "rm -Rf $TMPDIR").

Perhaps you have diferences between trunk and branches like:

Trunk:
/tmp/12/code/file.java

Branches:
/tmp/br1/12/code/file.java